# Если смысл использовать login activity в Android Studio? Или писать самому?

Tags: android

Если смысл использовать login activity в Android Studio? Или писать самому?

Comment: если ли смысл купить в магазине яблоки или лучше дома дерево вырастить? если ли смысл писать программы или лучше заказать? если ли смысл сделать велосипед?

Answer (score 2):

Login Activity из Android Studio логинится в Google Plus. Если вам надо логиниться в другое место, то смотрите сами, можете переделать существующее activity, а можете написать свое. 
Я предпочел написать свое, т.к. в login Activity слишком много левого кода и было в лом с ним разбираться. 
Но если вы планируете использовать OpenId, то Login Activity может вам пригодиться, т.к. по моему эта возможность там используется.